# Given integers how do I find asc and desc sequences of three?

Tags: ruby

I have integers i.e. `9`, `5`, `4`, `3`, `1`, `6`, `7`, `8`. I want to return the index where a sequence of three descending or ascending integers exists. In the example above I would get indices `1` and `5`. What is the ruby code for this?

```
def seq
  array = [9,5,4,3,1,6,7,8]
  array.each_with_index |val, index| 
    if (val < (array[index + 1]).val < (array[index + 1]).val) 
     puts "#{index}"
     # Skip two indexes 
    end
end
```

Comment: So by "ascending" and "descending" you specifically mean sequences with step +1 or -1 respectively? Would [9,5,4,3,2] return indexes 1 and 2?

Comment: [9,5,4,3,2] would return 1 only for my requirements, but if you'd like to spice it up feel free to bring in your spin to it.

Comment: @Bruno: That requirement is harder. How about `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`? Does that return just `[0]`, or should it return `[0,3]`, or would `[0,1,2,3]` be acceptable?

Comment: @NeilSlater Given that requirement, I think it's actually much easier. A traditional procedural approach is very straight-forward.

Comment: @meagar: OK, I think I see, although I'd still like to know which of the three options for `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` is preferable.

Comment: @NeilSlater His sample code says "skip two indexes" when a set is found, so I'd guess he'd expect `[0,3]`, for `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`. I don't think he's after overlapping sets. Both solutions are very trivial though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic behind your solution is almost correct, but your syntax is pretty far off from valid Ruby.

Here are a pair of pretty verbose solutions that will (hopefully) be fairly obvious:

```
numbers = [9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 7, 8]

# Find non-overlapping sets
i = 0
until i > numbers.length - 2
  a, b, c = numbers[i..i + 2]
  if (a - b == b - c) && (a - b).abs == 1
    puts "#{i} (#{a},#{b},#{c})"
    # Skip next two indexes
    i += 3
  else
    i += 1
  end
end

# Find overlapping sets (same solution, but don't skip indexes)
(0...numbers.length - 2).each do |i|
  a, b, c = numbers[i..i + 2]
  if (a - b == b - c) && (a - b).abs == 1
    puts "#{i} (#{a},#{b},#{c})"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since the question is not clear enough. I will assume the question is about finding 3 ascending or descending continuous numbers. If the length of the satisfied sequence it longer than 3, e.g [2, 3, 4, 5], it returns 0 and 1.**

Here is the algorithm, do `list[index] - list[index - 1]` for all elements, and repeat it for another time, the answer will be the index of 0 elements after the calculation.

Intuitively,

```
original       9,  5,  4,  3,  1,  6,  7, 8
first pass    -4, -1, -1, -2,  5,  1,  1
2nd pass       3,  0, -1,  7,  4,  0  -> the answer will be the indexes of 0's, which is 1, 5
```

*Algorithm*:

```
lst = [9, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 7, 8]
lst1 = lst.each_cons(2).map{ |a, b| b-a }
lst2 = lst1.each_cons(2).map{ |a, b| b-a }
result = lst2.each_index.select{|i| lst2[i] == 0}

result = [1, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a solution using `each_cons(3).with_index`:

```
[9,5,4,3,1,6,7,8].each_cons(3).with_index.select { |s, i| s[0] < s[1] && s[1] < s[2] }.map(&:last)
```

Comment: your and my one on the same page,but `map(&:last)` is not expected,OP wants the index..

Comment: @Babai No, they are not the same. Yours requires a variable to lookup the index while mine uses `with_index` to incorporate the index into the array. That’s also why `map(&:last)` is needed.